# Boostrap datepicker. Select current date as default IF not date has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I have a view that is re-used in the cases of

1) When a new object is created.
2) When we update some of the object's properties.

One of these properties is the **date**.

I wonder how can I make bootstrap datepicker work so it can **check** if the input field has a value at the moment of the view loads or, if it's empty, set the current date as default.

I only have this at the moment (to set the current date)

```
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            "setDate": new Date(),
            "autoclose": true
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });

</script>
```

But, of course, it's replacing the dates in those cases where the object had a date already saved, and I would like to keep that date unless the users decides to update it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try...

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        "autoclose": true
    }).filter(function(){
        //filter just the ones that do not have a value
        return ( '01/01/0001' === this.value || ( this.value || '' ).trim().length < 1 )
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is already now overwriting in the case of an existing date, but in the case of new dates it's not setting on the current date when opening the datepicker

Comment: Could be because the minimun date is 01/01/0001 instead of null/empty?

Comment: Yep! The default date when the view is loaded is 01/01/0001

Comment: Try the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{ String currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); }
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DATE)
         @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DATE))
         {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DATE, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @Value = currentDate })
          }
        else
       {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DATE, new { @class = "form-control datepicker"})
        }
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DATE)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working on asp.net